# MS WORD Changing Page Margins / Setting Print Margins without changing document layout

Tags: microsoft-word, margins

I have a certain layout in word document that is 250 pages. Unfortunately, it has 0.5 page margins. Is there a way to simply increase the paper/page size so that I will have 1 inch margins without messing up the look/format of my text?

Comment: The contents of your document will reflow when you change the margins unless you have all your content laid out in text frames. This is to be expected and there can't be much done about it.

Answer (score 0):

On the Page Layout tab click on "Size." From the dropdown options choose "More Paper Sizes." Specify the width and height you want (in your case 9 x 11.5). Then click the Margins tab in the open Page Setup dialog box, enter 1" for all margins, and click OK.